# App Engine socket error: [Errno 98] Address already in use

Tags: python, python-2.7, sockets, google-app-engine

I can't seem to find a solution to google app engine local server listening to a port number. I have tried several port number and I keep getting the "Address already in use" error. I have check for the availability of the ports and they are not in use.

I am trying to run the sample hello_world app for the python standard app engine, I have python 2.7.12 installed on my system, below is the output:

```
dev_appserver.py --port=8085  app.yaml
INFO     2017-08-22 15:11:15,041 devappserver2.py:116] Skipping SDK update check.
INFO     2017-08-22 15:11:15,264 api_server.py:313] Starting API server at: http://localhost:32989
INFO     2017-08-22 15:11:15,269 dispatcher.py:226] Starting module "default" running at: http://localhost:8085
INFO     2017-08-22 15:11:15,271 api_server.py:945] Applying all pending transactions and saving the datastore
INFO     2017-08-22 15:11:15,271 api_server.py:948] Saving search indexes
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jade/Dev/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py", line 103, in <module>
    _run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "/home/jade/Dev/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py", line 97, in _run_file
    execfile(_PATHS.script_file(script_name), globals_)
  File "/home/jade/Dev/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/devappserver2.py", line 381, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/jade/Dev/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/devappserver2.py", line 369, in main
    dev_server.start(options)
  File "/home/jade/Dev/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/devappserver2.py", line 201, in start
    admin.start()
  File "/home/jade/Dev/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/admin/admin_server.py", line 114, in start
    super(AdminServer, self).start()
  File "/home/jade/Dev/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/wsgi_server.py", line 330, in start
    self._start_all_fixed_port(host_ports)
  File "/home/jade/Dev/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/wsgi_server.py", line 354, in _start_all_fixed_port
    server.start()
  File "/home/jade/Dev/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/wsgi_server.py", line 255, in start
    self.socket.listen(self.request_queue_size)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 228, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 98] Address already in use
```

I have checked on other solutions on stackoverflow but none of the suggestions are working for me. Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

```
Address already in use
```

This error means you're already running a server on this port. To solve, you'll either have to find the other server running on your machine and terminate it, or pick a different port for your server to run on:

```
dev_appserver.py --port=8087  app.yaml
```

Answer (score -2):

I had the same issue before. I found that restarting my computer helped and then just making sure you fully kill the server using ctrl + c next time when you want to stop it.